# Is there a way to recover my vi-edited file?

Tags: data-recovery, vi

2 days ago, I remotely logged into my school's Unix system and wrote a lengthy file with vi. I saved with `:wq` and reopened it multiple times to check if it saved (it did).

Today, I log back in and open the file again. But, it's completely empty, like I created the file and didn't write anything! So, is there a swp or tmp file that my code saved into, for back-up? Is there any way to get the code back?

I suspect my TA logged into the account and deleted my code, because that's the only person besides the operator who knows my password. After this, I'm going to ALWAYS save a copy onto my own hard drive.

Comment: So... are you looking for a way to get rid of your TA? I can't see any other "problem" here, to be honest (expect of course, sharing your password) :') You may put some faith in data recovery tools such as `extundelete`, but there's no certainty you could get your file back...

Comment: I'm asking if there's any way to get my file back if it was actually deleted. I'm not blaming my TA either, that's just me venting. Every time in the past I edit a file with vi, it tells me there's a swp file. But now It says there isn't even one!

Comment: vi can create backups but I believe that's only after you specifically set it in your .vimrc file: http://www.gmarks.org/vi_backups.html

Comment: I'm not a vi user, but I wouldn't expect the backup files to remain on disk once the true file has been saved and persisted. They're usually here to prevent data loss in extreme situations such as disk crashing or power shutdown. I don't think it would naturally prevent a `rm file` call made later on.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: Right. `vi -r` can be used to recover a file from the swap file, but this works only if `vi` was abnormally terminated (e.g., `kill`ed). When `vi` exits normally, it deletes its swap file.

Comment: Actually, yes it does coincide with a time I wasn't logged in. My last true login was at 1PM, and it says I logged in again at 2AM. It turns out,  the operator has restore points every night. I hope that gets me back the file... (problem solved?)

Comment: Well...if true then that is a very big ethics violation and is a good way to get removed from a school. Just remember to keep calm when investigation and not rely on emotion. Although, a 1 hour difference might just be a bad clock. Check `last`..

Comment: @SailorCire, 13 hours. ;-)